# pyspark clickhouse jdbc driver no suitable driver

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, clickhouse

i'm really new with pyspark, i want to connect from pyspark to clickhouse, i found clickhouse spark jdbc jar file (clickhouse-integration-spark_2.11-2.7.1.jar) at maven

> com.github.housepower
>     clickhouse-integration-spark_2.11
>     2.7.1

and here is my simple pyspark code :

> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>
> spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars",
> "/path/clickhouse-integration-spark_2.11-2.7.1.jar")
> .master("local").appName("PySpark_Postgres").getOrCreate() jdbcDF = spark.read 
> .format("jdbc") 
> .option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123") 
> .option("dbtable", "default.test") 
> .load() jdbcDF.show()

but i get error :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

can anyone help